# Getting 'deprecated' warnings whilst using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm getting these warnings everything I run Mechanize with Ruby.

```
mechanize/cookie will be deprecated.  Please migrate to the http-cookie APIs.
mechanize/cookie_jar will be deprecated.  Please migrate to the http-cookie APIs.
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to change my code so that these errors clear away.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}

title = a.get('http://google.com').title
puts title
```

I suppose I need to install something that satisfies these requirements?

*Please migrate to the http-cookie APIs.*

**Edit 1**

Installing `gem install http-cookie` doesn't make a difference with regards to these warnings. I can't tell if Mechanize knows to use `http-cookie` or if it just uses the incorrect `cookie_jar` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I get errors like these I do something like the following:

```
bundle list my_gem
cd <DIR>
ag 'Please migrate to'
```

That usually points me to the source of the problem

EDIT: note going to the http-cookies github shows that it was extracted from Mechanize: https://github.com/sparklemotion/http-cookie

Comment: Thank you. I've run `gem install http-cookie` but of course Mechanize doesn't detect this. I wonder what else I can do to remove the warnings.

Comment: Working backwards, I found one of the warnings here: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize/cookie_jar.rb You could try to find where that file is `require`d or try and figure out if you can flip off that `$VERBOSE` flag